# How can I start a new digest cycle in angularjs so that variables are picked up by the web page?

Tags: angularjs

I have a variable that changes after or during a digest cycle, and that variable is not reflected in the web page that references it via AngularJS until a button is pressed - any button in fact.

I tried a setTimeout wrapping a scope.apply, and I made the timeout sufficiently long that the timeout does occur after the variable changes, but no success at getting the change to be reflected in the web page.

I added this code, which according to a different post on Stack Overflow, should be bulletproof:

```
setTimeout(function  () {
   $scope.$apply(function () {
$scope.message = "Timeout called";
//ADDED BELOW
$scope.curentUserAuthority = GlobalService.currentUserAuthority;
$scope.currentUserViewName = GlobalService.currentUserViewName;
//ADDED ABOVE
LoggingService.info('Timeout called!!!');
});
}, 10000);
```

The timeout does occur after the variable changes, and the message "Timeout called" is printed to console, but nothing happens with the web page. I thought that a $scope.apply would start a brand new digest cycle just like clicking a button. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your time.

EDIT: This works when I add the two lines between the ADDED comments above.
What I don't understand is why I must do this when I have watch routines looking for changes in these variables. Example of one

```
$scope.$watch('currentUserAuthority', function() {
LoggingService.info(' WATCHING YOU currentUserAuthority is '+$scope.currentUserAuthority);
});
```

The function above never fires until AFTER my $scope.$apply function executes as a result of my timeout. Weird. Am I not understanding something?

Comment: the code looks good except that minus sign `$scope.message - "Timeout called";`

Comment: That is a typo. It's OK in code.

Comment: okay then what is the problem?  show your template

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "show your template". The problem is that the $watch method does not fire as a result of a change to the variable it is watching.  I had to put in the $apply method shown above wrapped in a setTimeout sufficient for the variables to be initialized. This solution seems rather goofy though. Even the $apply did not work until I specifically set the $scope variables inside of the $apply method.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to reference state that is in some other service and the modification of that state will not trigger a digest on your local scope or scopes.

The state for the component you're working with should be isolated to that component or a parent component rather than a service.

It's impossible to specify exactly how you "should" implement this as angularJS is a multi paradigm framework, but I can give you a few different ways you can accomplish this.

Using the component API in angular1.5+ you would have a parent component that will hold the "one source of truth" state and you can then get updates via one way bindng and '<' and $onChanges()

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Using $scope.$broadcast / $scope.$emit events you can from anywhere broadcast changes either up or down the scope chain (or even $broadcast from $rootScope to hit all $scopes) Using this you can follow a pub sub model where when your state needs to be updated you can $broadcast or $emit events and have the relevant controllers listen for those events with $on

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope (look for propagation)

I don't really recommend this unless you are doing DOM wide manipulation (maybe you are, I have a very good use case for this myself)

Lastly you can still use watchers, but this data should be passed in by other directives / ng-controller / routes / components. This would again require one directive / ng-controller directive to pass these values to child directives.